# Can't boot Win7 laptop from dvd/usb to install Ubuntu 14.04 for dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

My laptop is a Lenovo T-510 running i7 @ 2.2GHz (I think; maybe 2.4GHz), 8gb ram, no discrete graphics card, and a 500gb hdd, and came preinstalled with Win7, Pro I think. It's been a great little laptop but I've been trying to install Ubuntu alongside Win7. I shrank the Windows partition and have 120gb of unallocated space to use for Ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded the 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 and tried running it from a flash drive and from a dvd and haven't been able to boot from either. They appear in the boot menu but when I try to boot from the usb it says it's an invalid disk and the dvd doesn't seem to do anything at all and Windows resumes normal startup as if it weren't even there.

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: Not sure if this makes much/any difference but my laptop runs BIOS, not UEFI.

Comment: How did you put it on the USB/DVD?

Comment: You need to use the Windows 7 image burner tool.

Comment: I downloaded the iso directly to a flash drive. Same flash drive I used to install in a htpc build. I burned from that to the dvd using Windows' burner tool (instead of copying and using the dvd like a flash drive)

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference but I just confirmed it is in fact Win7 Pro. Could the drive protection be different/more strict because of this?

Comment: No, it's more likely a secure boot option in your BIOS.  Try running the autorun content from the DVD/USB

Comment: The autorun on the usb seems to just be a notepad file with a couple of commands to open wubi and install Ubuntu 14.04 through that. I need to read up a little on wubi before going any further but it looks like that could work, at least well enough for me. Thanks! If I could upvote your autorun answer I would

Comment: I'll give an actual answer.

Comment: What does the contents of the DVD and USB-drive look like when you open them in Windows?  If it only contains a single ISO file, you are not doing it right.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - Yessir, or ma'am. When I installed Ubuntu on a blank drive just the ISO had sufficed, and I didn't realize I needed to format the flash drive into a startup drive. Hopped onto a different computer and did that, popped it in, booted from it, and everything went perfectly. I want to thank everyone again for their time and answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. You need to disable `Secure Boot` in your BIOS.  This [tutorial](http://packard-bell-scandic.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27071/~/how-to-enable-or-disable-secure-boot) will help give you an idea of what you need to do to do this.
2. Try running `wubi.exe` from the USB/DVD.  This may work for you.  While I've never personally, I've heard that it works well.  I may try this myself one of these days (maybe when 16.04 LTS comes out!).

Comment: The last version of wubi that was maintained was 12.04. Not sure why file is still on every distribution. It does not work with new UEFI/gpt systems. Some advanced users are able to make newer wubi work with BIOS/MBR systems, but it is not the easy to install system that was originally intended.

Comment: If he installs 12.04 with wubi, he can upgrade to 14.04 in OS.

Comment: Theoretically...

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I'm a complete rookie. I decided to start over as I hadn't been able to find a fix by troubleshooting mid-process. I finally saw something I'd been missing: I hadn't gone through the process of making the flash drive into a startup disk. I'd only ever loaded an OS onto a blank drive before so I had no idea that process was necessary when installing on a disk drive that already has an OS on it.

I really appreciate everyone's input on this. I've got this page bookmarked for future reference and will check this site first from now on.